# this script must be run from the base directory of your working copy

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, command-line

I am trying to execute an Android script to generate the Eclipse version of a library.

The script is on:

```
/Users/fabiom/Documents/LibrerieANDROID/android-basic-samples-master/scripts/make_eclipse_compat
```

But, I have this error:

```
this script must be run from the base directory of your working copy
```

Can someone help me?

UPDATE:

someone Can run the script for me and pass me the eclipse version ? https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the directory in wich you are. You have to run the script from the base directory.

In order to do so, open the terminal and go to the base directory:

```
cd /Users/fabiom/Documents/LibrerieANDROID/android-basic-samples-master
```

Then run the script from there:

```
Scripts/make_eclipse_compat
```

You shoud see *Eclipse-compatible folders generated in eclipse_compat*

The Eclipse versions should be inside this new directory.

If you are using Windows, run **Scripts/make_eclipse_compat.cmd** instead of **Scripts/make_eclipse_compat**

Comment: I get this error when I try the command `'Scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I fixed the above by copying the make_eclipse_compat.cmd file up one directory and running it there and it worked

Answer (score 0):

From what I have figured out, Here are the steps you need to follow to get this working.

1) Download the BaseGameUtils file from here https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwANZFc0H24cOWlNRFlaOGtLbnc/edit

2) Extract the file and import it in eclipse.

3) GameHelper class will give errors. Copy the replace the entire code of GameHelper class with the code give in this link https://gist.github.com/EmmanuelVinas/ef09a35bcc805ba6deb3

4) Finally include the package name com.google.example.games.basegameutils on top of the GameHelper class.

That's all you need to do.